# After HealthKit access go to ViewController but elements show after 5 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, healthkit

In my app I ask for HealthKit access and that works fine. I get permission to read the step count and flights climbed. After the permissions are authorized I want to send the user to a new `ViewController`. This works fine but the elements in that `ViewController` are shown after like 5/6 seconds. I've put the elements in the `ViewController` by storyboard. If I add elements with code they are shown directly.

How is this possible? I want all elements to show up directly when the `ViewController` is loaded.

This is my code I use to check if the HealthKit is authorized and send the user to the next `ViewController`:

```
healthManager.authorizeHealthKit { (authorized,  error) -> Void in
    if authorized {
        let vc : AnyObject = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainVC")
        self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
    } else {
        if error != nil {
           println("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not following the issue you are having. You might need to pull data before you load the app. Sometimes Healthkit is slow to respond (lots of data) an thus the delay. You want might want to load it before you push view maybe in AppDelegate and pass it to your view.

Comment: The delay is indeed the problem. I can't access HealthKit data before the user has given permission and I don't get a success block of anything when the data is accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HealthKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html):

> After the user has finished responding, this method calls its completion block on a background queue.

You should do all the UI-related things on the main thread, so just dispatch it there

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    let vc : AnyObject = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainVC")
    self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
}
```

Comment: I saw that in the documentation but I put it in the wrong ViewController, thanks.